# Polly with IDistributedCache and IHttpClientFactory Policy

Tags: c#, caching, .net-6.0, polly, retry-logic

Using the following code compiles fine, but receives the runtime error below.  Seems to be a conflict between the policy only supporting `HttpResponseMessage` when using `IHttpClientFactory`?
The end goal is to be able to use several policies like retry, timeout, etc. and if everything is OK cache the result with the cache policy...

> Unable to cast object of type
> 'Polly.Caching.AsyncCachePolicy'1[System.String]' to type
> 'Polly.IAsyncPolicy'1[System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage]'.'

```
serviceCollection.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
{
    options.Configuration = "...";
});
IPolicyRegistry<string> registry = serviceCollection.AddPolicyRegistry();
var cacheProvider = ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDistributedCache>().AsAsyncCacheProvider<string>();
serviceCollection.AddSingleton(serviceProvider => cacheProvider);

AsyncCachePolicy<string> cachePolicy =
Policy.CacheAsync(
    cacheProvider: cacheProvider,
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
registry.Add("CachingPolicy", cachePolicy);

serviceCollection.AddHttpClient<IMyClient, MyClient>()
    .AddPolicyHandlerFromRegistry(this.PolicySelector)
    
private IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> PolicySelector(IReadOnlyPolicyRegistry<string> policyRegistry, HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage)
{
    return policyRegistry.Get<IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>>("CachingPolicy");
}
```

Comment: You are caching the policy as a type of AsyncCachePolicy<string>, and then trying to resolve it as a type of AsyncCachePolicy<HttpResponseMessage>. Not sure what are you trying to achievet, but that is the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says you can not convert `AsyncCachePolicy<string>` to `IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>`. Since all `AsyncXYZPolicy` implements the `IAsyncPolicy` interface that's why the problem is not coming from here. Rather than from the type parameter.

The `AddHttpClient` returns an `IHttpClientBuilder`. There are [several extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.pollyhttpclientbuilderextensions.addpolicyhandler?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) on them like `AddPolicyHandlerFromRegistry`, `AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy` or `AddPolicyHandler`. In all cases you need to register a policy where the return type is `HttpResponseMessage`.

If you would try to register your cache policy directly via the `AddPolicyHandler` then it would cause compilation error rather than run-time error. But because you retrieve the policy dynamically from the registry that's why it throws exception at runtime.

#### How to fix it?

Rather than defining a policy as `AsyncCachePolicy<string>` you should define it as `AsyncCachePolicy<HttpResponseMessage>`. To do that you need to change the type parameter of the `AsAsyncCacheProvider` method.

```
var cacheProvider = ServiceProvider
   .GetRequiredService<IDistributedCache>()
   .AsAsyncCacheProvider<HttpResponseMessage>();
```

You also need to change the `cachePolicy`'s type

```
AsyncCachePolicy<HttpResponseMessage> cachePolicy =
Policy.CacheAsync(
    cacheProvider: cacheProvider,
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

---

Side note: I would also suggest to store the policy registry key (`"CachingPolicy"`) in a constant and refer to it when you register that and when you retrieve that.

---

**UPDATE #1**:

I'm not even sure that you have to call the `AsAsyncCacheProvider` method at all. Let me double check.

---

**UPDATE #2**

After reading the source code of the [`AsAsyncCacheProvider`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly.Caching.IDistributedCache/blob/ed8e03a2ea2b32cd203869ceb529ef5618cf2fe6/src/Polly.Caching.Distributed/CacheProviderHelper.cs#L37) I've realized that it only supports `byte[]` or `string` as a type parameter. This indicates that you can't use the `AddPolicyHandler` methods here to automatically cache the response.

Rather you have to use the `AsyncPolicyCache<string>` directly in your `MyClient` implementation. You need to modify the constructor of the `MyClient` to recieve an `IReadonlyPolicyRegister<string>` parameter as well.

```
private readonly IAsyncPolicy<string> _cachePolicy;
public MyClient(HttpClient client, IReadOnlyPolicyRegistry<string> policyRegistry)
{
    _cachePolicy = policyRegistry.Get<IAsyncPolicy<string>>("CachingPolicy");
    // ...
}
```

And inside your exposed method you need to explicitly use `ExecuteAsync`

```
await _cachePolicy.ExecuteAsync(context => getXYZ(), new Context("XYZUniqueKey"));
```

The `getXYZ` needs to return a string (potentially the response body).

Comment: I also came to this same conclusion.  I decided not to use it because: 1. It's not seamless like it is with the in-memory cache provider and IHttpClientFactory.  I don't want to have to wrap all my http calls with this goofy syntax. 2.  I couldn't even get it to work with streaming responses and reading headers (e.g. pagination,etc) they were also empty. I might still use the other policies.  I'll handle the caching outside of this library.